# Why does F# Set need IComparable?

Tags: f#

So I am trying to use the F# Set as a hash table. But my element type doesn't implement the `IComparable` interface (although it implements `IEquatable`). I got an error saying the construction is not allowed because of comparison constraint. And through some further read, I discovered that F# Set is implemented using binary tree, which makes insertion causes `O(log(n))`. This looks weird to me, why is the Set structure designed this way?

Edit: So I learned that `Set` in F# is actually a `SortedSet`. And I guess the question becomes, why is Sorted Set somehow more preferable than a general Hash Set as an immutable/functional data structure?

Comment: "*Why is the Set structure designed this way?*" What else would you possibly expect?

Comment: For a hashset no sorting is required, therefore isn't equality good enough?

Comment: Yes, but why would you expect `Set` (which is an immutable/functional data structure) to necessarily be a hashset rather than an ordered set? What lead to this expectation?

Comment: Oh because many material I found states that Set is F#'s version of HashSet. Maybe it's a premature thought, but I kinda expect F# to have a basic Hash Set collection

Comment: `Set` is F#'s version of _`SortedSet`_. I'm not aware of any purely functional hashsets, at least I don't remember seeing any in the Okasaki book... That said, because F# can use any other .NET type, it can use `HashSet` without issues, as long as one is okay with a mutable data structure.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know HashSet is not used much in functional languages. That's interesting point though.

Comment: @ildjam Scala has an immutable HashSet implementation (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashSet), also Clojure: http://clojure.org/data_structures#toc24. Seems Haskell also have one: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashmap-1.0.0.2/docs/Data-HashSet.html, but it seems to require `Ord` too.

Comment: @GáborBakos : Immutable, or purely functional?

Comment: @ildjarn They are immutable, from the outside they are purely functional, they are using structural sharing. Not sure whether inside they are purely functional or not, but to be honest I would not care much about if they were not. If interested, you can check the sources.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two important points that should help you understand how sets in F# (and in functional languages in general) work and how they are used:

- Implementing immutable hashtables (like .NET `HashSet`) is hard - when you remove or add elements, you want to avoid copying everything in the data structure and (as far as I know) there is no general way of doing that (you would end up copying too much, so it would be inefficient).

  For this reason, most functional sets are implemented as (some form of trees). Those require comparison to build a sorted tree. The nice property of balanced trees is that removing and adding elements does not have to copy everything in the tree, so even the worst case scenario is reasonably efficient (though mutable hashtable is still faster).
- Now, F# is functional-first, which means that immutable structures are preferred, but it is perfectly fine to use mutable data structures (especially if you limit the usage to some well defined and restricted scope). For this reason, F# programmers often use `Dictionary` or `HashSet`, especially when this is only within the scope of a single function.